# Should we check no changes in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing

This example is custom made to ask my doubt.

```
Object Car {
  color:null
  tyre : 0;
}

fillCar(Object Car, boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        Car.color = "Red"
    } else {
        Car.tyre = 4;
    } 
}
```

Now i need to unit test my code.

My test1 is (Car, true) and test2 is (Car, false).

My question:

Do i need to test "tyres == 4" when in test1 and on similar lines do i need to check "color == null" when test2 ?

Comment: That doesn't look like Java.  Is it Javascript?

Comment: In general it's difficult to test that a method had no unintended side effects, because the number of possible side effects are infinite.  But if they can be enumerated in a spec, then they can be tested in a test.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is YES if this is part of the functional requirement of the method.

For example, if your specifications say that when **True** the value of **tyre** must be 4 and other variables will not matter, then it is not necessary. But if your specifications say that not only **tyre** must be 4 but the rest of variables must remain with the same value, then  you should check that out too.

Take into account that Unit test not only are useful for checking that your code is fine, but also for making sure that when your code in the future, you do not corrupt the expected functionality.

Comment: It seems we answered at the same time. I agree with this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there is no harm in testing all parts of the code. In fact, I would encourage it. It's a very easy way of checking that no mistakes have been made in the logic.

In this case, the code is simple enough to see the result. However, it could become much more complex if Car is extended, or more functionality added.

Comment: I tend to disagree to an extent.  Overzealous, overreaching tests (i.e. test that test more than just their public functionality) make code difficult to refactor and don't really deliver much value.  It's the reason why Mockito, for example, give you big warnings on methods like `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions()`.

Comment: Here's a link that Mockito includes with all of their warnings about over-specifying tests:  http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/07/12/should-i-worry-about-the-unexpected/.

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes, there is obviously a degree of compromise between well-tested code and flexible code. In this case, it appears to be public-facing, and with non-obvious outputs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of argument about this but unit testing started to make sense to me once I focused on verifying the interface. In this case you have a function which exposes an interface where you can pass in a car-object and a boolean and then have certain modifications made to the car object depending on the value of the boolean. You quite rightly see two unit tests covering that and personally I would stop there. If you are worried about nulls showing up you can cover that in the unit tests when the car objects are constructed. If you assign something other than a straight forward literal that might be a null then tests for nulls would make sense.

One more tip - unit testing works much better for me within the context of test driven design (TDD). YMMV but I find non-TDD code very hard to unit test.

Finally - just a mention that I found learning TDD/unit-testing is well worth it.